# comparison of xml and xsd in C#

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to compare the schema structure of 2 xmls.For that purpose I created xsd from one xml and then comparig that xsd (schema structure) with another xml...so that I can know whether both xml have same structure or not.

following is xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <bookstore xmlns="generic">
       <book genre="autobiography">
           <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
           <author>
               <first-name>Ben</first-name>
               <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
           </author>
           <price>89.88</price>
       </book>
       <book genre="novel">
           <title>The Confidence Man</title>
           <author>
               <first-name>John</first-name>
               <last-name>Melville</last-name>
           </author>
           <price>11.99</price>
       </book>
    </bookstore>

and following is generated  xsd from above xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="bookstore" targetNamespace="generic" xmlns:mstns="generic" xmlns="generic" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="bookstore" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="book">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
              <xs:element name="price" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              <xs:element name="author" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="first-name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="last-name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="genre" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

now when I compare xml with xsd with following code:

```
try
            {
                XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(xsd);
                XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
                schema.Add(null, tr);

                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                settings.IgnoreComments = true;
                settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
                settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
                settings.Schemas.Add(schema);
                settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
                settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ErrorHandler);

                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml, settings);

                // Validate XML data
                while (reader.Read()) ;
                reader.Close();

                // exception if validation failed
                if (numErrors > 0)
                    throw new Exception(a);

                tr.Close();
                a = "Validation Successful\r\n";
                return a;
            }
            catch
            {
                a = "Validation failed\r\n" + a;
                return a;
            }
```

validation fail as order in xsd and xml is differrence .heere in case of price...........
My question is how to ignore the order..

help will be appreciable

Comment: But if you don't know what the proper schema is for these pieces of XML, you can't assume that order doesn't matter - in some schemas, order **does** matter.

Comment: proper schema will be same as that of xml

Comment: If you want that the elements can appear in any order, then you probably want to use `xs:choice` with an unbounded `maxOccurs`, rather than `xs:sequence`, in the XSD. As the name implies, an `xs:sequence` defines a sequence of elements - your XSD is saying that the elements should appear in exactly that order.